# Is there a zsh equivalent to the function-in-alias idiom?

Tags: zsh, zshrc

After *many* years, I'm giving zsh a try. I have

```
alias rsync='rsync -av --progress --stats --human-readable'
```

and also a lot of aliases like this in my bash .profile

```
alias workin='function _workin(){ rsync -avE --progress --stats --human-readable -e ssh me@$1:/there/ /here; };_workin'
```

I've been unable to figure out how to get this to work in zsh. I keep getting errors of the sort 'no matches found'. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you putting a function in an alias instead of just using the function?

Comment: It was how I ultimately figured out how to do things like issue the command in bash "rsync 1.1.1.13" and it would automagically do what I wanted. If there's a better way, *please* let me know.

Comment: The better way is what 123 said: Just use the function.

Comment: Don't use the bash tag in zsh questions.

Comment: (and as per the comments -- even in bash, just write `workin() { rsync -avE --progress --stats --human-readable -e ssh me@"$1":/there/ /here; }`. BTW, note that ssh is the default transport for rsync, and has been literally for decades now, so there's no need for the `-e`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I don't feel strongly about this, but: I think it's reasonable to include the 'bash' tag for questions about differences between Bash and Zsh, even if the motivation for the question is to get something working in Zsh.

Comment: @ruakh, I'd argue that the justification for including a tag is that subject-matter experts in that tag will be able to help. *In general*, someone who knows bash but not zsh isn't going to be of use in a zsh-specific question, even when the question is contrasting zsh to bash. (This is somewhat of an unusual case, since it's asking about a practice that isn't considered good form in either shell -- but encouraging that particular hair-splitting makes it more difficult to have a hard-and-fast rule).

Comment: Sorry, @CharlesDuffy I'm generally pretty useless everywhere :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution, in `bash` *and* `zsh`, is to dispense with the alias altogether.

```
workin () {
  rsync -avE --progress --stats --human-readable -e ssh me@"$1":/there/ /here
}
```

(Whether or not you need to quote `$1` depends on what settings you are using; `zsh` is somewhat *too* configurable. But, it won't *hurt* to quote it, so I'll do so here.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why I was using functions in aliases in bash: it was a long time ago, and habits change hard. 123 and melpomene showed me the way in the comments, so if anyone is thinking of doing the same in zsh, here's a great StackExchange explanation of a better way: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33255/how-to-define-and-load-your-own-shell-function-in-zsh